# How to write conditional - if current date and time is before last day of month 11:59

Tags: javascript, jquery

With JavaScript how would I write a conditional statement checking if the current date and time (UTC), is before the last day 11:59 pm of current month. I don't want to use third-part libraries.

For example:

Date must be in UTC timezone.

```
if(todays_date_and_time < this_months_last_day_at_11_and_59pm) {
  function1();
} else {
  function2();
}
```

Comment: Are you essentially trying to work out "is the time within _this_ month"? If so: it might be easier to check "is time less than 00:00:00 of the new month".

Comment: yes I guess that is essentially what I'm trying to figure out. Please offer a solution.

Comment: actually, am I missing something? isn't "current date and time" **by definition** always within the current month?
also, there are many edge cases around date manipulation and comparison. if you are willing to relax the "no third-party libraries" constraint, you will find [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) will really make this problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution is very simple.

```
// This is function which checks your date

function checkDate(ms){
    ms = ms || Date.now();
    return (new Date(ms)).getUTCDate() <= (new Date(ms + 6e4)).getUTCDate();
}

checkDate(); // Check current date
checkDate(1479586906627); // Check specified date

// If you want if statement, you can do it as following

if(checkDate()){
    function1();
}else{
    function2();
}
```

How does it work? It checks if we can reach next month in one minute. If yes, it means that new day of the month will be smaller than the current day, so it simply compares these two values.

Comment: This checks if you can reach the given _day_ in one minute. But yes, if your input param is "00:00:00 of the first day of the new month", then that works.

Comment: @Birchlabs. It check if the current day is smaller or equal than the next day. Think about it. If next day is next month, current day will be larger. Do you understand how it works?

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to have to specify the date manually. It should check against the last day of the current month.

Comment: @beliy333. You didn't read my answer carefully. I said that if you pass no arguments it will check the current month.